# Is JSON.parse() necessary?

Tags: parsing, json

I'm retrieving some data from my server using PHP. I want to use this data in a javascript application so I'm doing something like this:

```
var polylines = <?php echo json_encode($polylines); ?>;
```

`$polylines` is simply a PHP array and the right hand side of this equation is merely a PHP string. But I've noticed that `polylines` now behaves as an object, even though I've never called the JSON.parse() function. So this leads me to the question, is JSON.parse() needed? Or will javascript "detect" that the string you've entered is json like, and automatically parse it as an object (like it appears to have done in this case)?

Comment: Take a look at the JavaScript code that arrives at the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, `JSON.parse()` is not needed in this case.

This code dumps a JSON text into the right-hand side of an assignment to a JavaScript variable. JSON is a strict subset of JavaScript, so what you're really doing here is *generating JavaScript code.* JavaScript doesn't "see" a string. The client-side parser sees a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: Ok thanks, so is JSON.parse() only needed when you have a javascript string of json-like text and you need it to be treated as an object instead?

Comment: Pretty much. I would correct that by saying this: `JSON.parse()` is needed when you have a javascript string of json text and you want to turn it into an object. ("JSON-like" isn't a meaningful descriptor and suggests more leniency than the JSON spec allows. In practice, however, you'll find varying degrees of leniency in different implementations of `JSON.parse()`.)

Comment: When in doubt, start by [reading the docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 2):

Depend upon how you are getting the php getting into client browser.
In this case you ll not get double quotes in javascript.

case 1:
var polylines = "[\"key\":12]";
for this case you have to do JSON.parse

case 2:
var polylines = ["key":12];
for this case you have no need to do JSON.parse. this one is your case.